# Why my SwiftUI List turn empty when scroll down?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI List pushed through NavigationLink. But when I scroll down the data suddenly turn empty. Not sure why? Xcode 14.2 Here's my implementation

- Parent View (doesn't has issue)

```swift
NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(viewModel.endorsements, id: \.name) { endorsement in
          EndorsementListItem(endorsement: endorsement)
            .background {
              NavigationLink {
                viewModel.buildEndorsmentListDetail(endorsement)
              } label: {
                EmptyView()
              }.opacity(0)
            }
          .padding(.vertical, 16)
          .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal, 12)
      .listStyle(.plain)
...
```

- Child View (which has the issue)

```swift
struct EndorsementListDetail: View {
var body: some View {
        List {
          ForEach(viewModel.endorsement.details) { detail in
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
              EndorsementListDetailItem(detail: detail)
              Divider()
            }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 12))
          }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
...
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHk4s.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcKlh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWVy8.png)

I'm expecting the list still has data when scroll down

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: The issue does not happen when I wrapped all my view in hosting vc, then put them all in a navigationController.
I guess something is wrong with SwiftUI NavigationLink.

Comment: In `NavigationLink`, have you tried to simply use `EndorsementListDetail(endorsement)` instead of trying
 to build a View inside a viewModel with `viewModel.buildEndorsmentListDetail(endorsement)`

Comment: Keep the endorsements in a state property, they get lost on body rebuild (scroll).